# How to avoid closing cmd after running command with win+r?

Tags: cmd

I press `Windows+R` to open run dialog box.
Then I write command `ipconfig /all` and press Enter.
`cmd` is opened with some network content but it closes immediately.

I want `cmd` not to close at all without my consent.

I googled that I can run two commands in windows run dialog when I separate them with `&` or `&&`. I also found out that `pause` or `set /p=` commands would stop `cmd` from closing. However, `ipconfig /all && pause` (and all 3 other combinations) fail - `cmd` still closes and the rest of the command is passed to `ipconfig` which "returns an error".

Comment: Why don't you just write a .cmd file and run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682048(v=VS.85).aspx):

> A console is closed when the last process attached to it terminates or calls FreeConsole.

In other words, Win32 console window will always be closed when the last program running inside it exits, and you cannot change this.

---

**Solutions:**

call `cmd.exe /k` first.

**example:**

```
cmd.exe /k ipconfig /all
```

With above trick, we call `cmd.exe` to execute `ipconfig /all`. Since `cmd.exe` not terminated, so the console will not closed.

Comment: Thank you! cmd /kipconfig/all for maximum productivity.

Comment: glad to help you sir :)